# Excerpt and taxonomies on SULU Admin

Tags: sulu

how can I hide or disable "Excerpt and taxonomies" tab on SULU Admin UI, on my custom page template?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate existing tabs by registering a custom Admin class and use the `$viewCollection->get` method to get the excerpt instance you could then hide it using a `setTabCondition`.

```php
public function configureViews(ViewCollection $viewCollection): void
{
    if ($viewCollection->has('sulu_page.page_edit_form.excerpt')) {
        $viewCollection->get('sulu_page.page_edit_form.excerpt')
            ->setTabCondition(false);
    }
}
```

Make sure the priority is lower then the original Admin Priority e.g.:

```php
public function static getPriority(): int
{
    return PageAdmin::getPriority() - 1;
}
```

Still I would not recommend hiding the excerpt tab as things like smart content which using the excerpt categories and tags.

Comment: But how can register custom Admin class, when that is part of webspaces... 

How can I issolate only that, when webspace is "dynamic".

Comment: The tabCondition is a "jexl" expression which has access to all data of the page response. For example `setTabCondition('webspace == "demo"')`.